# Updating cloudfoundry vmc on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-foundry

how do i update vmc client on ubuntu to version so that it supports tunnel to services like mysql.

I want to use the tunnel, but prerequisite is:
You must have vmc 0.3.14 or later.

Now, when i check my version, it says 0.3.10.
If i run gem update vmc, it says nothing to update.

So, my question is, am i updating wrong? Or is it not supported yet on linux platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version does Rubygems say was installed? If it says version 0.3.18 (the latest version) and you are using RVM, it may be worth making sure that when you run VMC your running the latest version installed.

Comment: i guess i got, i updated my ruby, then other things. I can connect to a tunnel now, though i cant quite connect to a service. I'll make a new question for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per my [blog post on this topic](http://andypiper.co.uk/2012/04/26/ubuntu-12-04-and-cloud-foundry/), the version of vmc that Ubuntu is shipping today is backlevel, so I'd recommend you go down a fresh gem install route.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
sudo gem install vmc
```

to get the latest stable version and

```
sudo gem install vmc --pre
```

to get the latest development version.